# Ubuntu Mono System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I use the KeeSkyDrive plugin for my KeePass,and it works very well on my PC.But doesn't work with Portable Keepass 2.24 on Ubuntu 12.04, Mono 2.10.8.1.
When click authorize button, it return "KeeSkyDrive Authorization Error" as follow:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   at system.windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigate(System.String urlString)[0x00000] in :0
>
> at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser:Navigate (string)
>
> at KeeSkyDrive.AuthenticationForm.Authenticate (System.String url, System.String targetUrl, IWin32Window owner)[0x00000] in :0
>
> at KeeSkyDrive.LiveConnection.GetAuthorizationCode (System.String[] scopes, IWin32Window owner) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at KeeSkyDrive.LiveConnection.Authorize (System.String[] scopes, Boolean implicitGrant, IWin32Window owner)[0x00000] in :0
>
> at KeeSkyDrive.OptionsForm.AuthorizeClick (System.Object sender, System.EvenArgs e)[0x00000] in :0

The source code of the plugin at sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/p/keeskydrive/code/ci/master/tree/

Here is the crash code I pasted:

```
public static string Authenticate(string url, string targetUrl, IWin32Window owner)
    {
        using (var form = new AuthenticationForm())
        {
            form.targetUrl = targetUrl;
            form.targetUrl = url;
            form.webBrowser.Navigate(url);
            var result = form.ShowDialog(owner);
            return result == DialogResult.OK ? form.webBrowser.Url.OriginalString : null;
        }
    }
```

Please some help modify the code of the plugin to run on ubuntu? Thanks.